# How do I fill the remainder of the visible page with a background color?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, flexbox

I have a page I'm trying fill some content with and then the remainder of the page fill with a background color. I've kind of been able to achieve this using `min-height: 100vh` but the problem is now my page scroll get's extended significantly. Is it possible just to color the visible space on the screen without increasing scrollable area on the page.

Here's a simple example with a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/knha3eLw/30/):

If you remove the `min-height: 100vh` from `.footer` notice that the colored square gets much smaller and now the scroll area isn't very large either. How do I only fill that area that's visible when not using the min-height style.

```css
.body {
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: grey;
  min-height: 100vh;
  z-index: -100;
  margin-top: -150px;
}

img {
  z-index: 100;
    margin-left: 200px;

}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-centerr">
    <h1>
    This is my page heading
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
    <p>
    This is some information about this page. 
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-centerr">
    <div class="justify-content-center">
      <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/RkBHz5tPuCNQOG0a6FooNwiqQyw=/0x0:939x704/1820x1213/filters:focal(0x0:939x704):format(webp)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49610677/homersimpson.0.0.jpg"
      width="300px"
      height="300px"
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="footer">
    <br />
  </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: The HTML and CSS you provided do not replicate the issue pictured in your OP

Comment: You can set a background-color on the `body` element, and then set a background-color to `.body` to be white;

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with, using `flexbox` and `flex-grow: 1` to force the element to grow and take up the remaining space and `flex-shrink: 0` to prevent the `img` and other elements from shrinking.

I had to add a new class to he footer's parent element, to add the `flexbox` class to it. note the `footer-parent` class.

```
<div class="body">
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
    <h1>
      This is my page heading
    </h1>
  </div>
  <div class="row justify-content-center text-center">
    <p>
      This is some information about this page.
    </p>
  </div>
  <div class="row footer-parent justify-content-center text-center">
    <div class="justify-content-center">
      <img src="https://cdn.vox-cdn.com/thumbor/RkBHz5tPuCNQOG0a6FooNwiqQyw=/0x0:939x704/1820x1213/filters:focal(0x0:939x704):format(webp)/cdn.vox-cdn.com/uploads/chorus_image/image/49610677/homersimpson.0.0.jpg" width="300px" height="300px" />
    </div>
    <div class="footer">
      <br />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's the CSS

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  margin-left: 50px;
  height: 100%;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

.footer {
  background-color: grey;
  flex-grow: 1;
  z-index: -100;
  margin-top: -150px;
}

.footer-parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-grow: 1;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
}

img {
  z-index: 100;
  flex-shrink: 0;
  margin-left: 200px;
}

h1 {
  flex-shrink: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```